# wso2 api manger carbon page gives 403 Forbidden

Tags: api, wso2

I've downloaded a fresh wso2 api manager and trying to open the link **http://host_name:9443/carbon**. It gives an error of 403 forbidden and the stack trace is :

```
- JavaLogger potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, ip:127.0.0.1, method:POST, uri:/carbon/admin/login_action.jsp, error:required token is missing from the request)
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 11):

This issue happens due a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789) in JDK 1.8.0_151, and you can proceed with approaches:

1. Downgrade from build 1.8.0_151 to 1.8.0_144;
2. But if you cannot proceed with the downgrade of, so you can disable the compression in Tomcat ***repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml***, switching compression to **"off"** instead of the default which is *"on"*.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use JDK1.8.0_151 due to a [known issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789). This issue is fixed in JDK 1.8.0_162-ea which is not released yet. Use JDK 1.8.0_144 until then.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Installation+Prerequisites

Comment: Sorry, above mentioned JDK 1.8.0_162-ea is the Open JDK, not Oracle one.

Answer (score 2):

Working with Java 1.8.0_161, just need to switch compressed "off" in catalina-server.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (to [Edgar Tarton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034714/wso2-api-manger-carbon-page-gives-403-forbidden/47041377#47041377)) you can disable CSRF prevention until the next jdk version is released by setting `org.owasp.csrfguard.Enabled` to false. This must be changed in the following files:

- $WSO2EI_HOME/wso2/business-process/conf/security/Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties
- $WSO2EI_HOME/wso2/analytics/conf/security/Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties
- $WSO2EI_HOME/wso2/broker/conf/security/Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties
- $WSO2EI_HOME/conf/security/Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties

Comment: This will only fix CSRF issue. There're other files that are gzipped too. So there can be other issues such as images not been shown properly etc, unless you change the JDK or disable compression.