# WSO2 Identity Server login returns a 403

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to log into my WSO2 management console. It is containerized and hosted in an AWS EC2 instance. I can navigate to the console login page, but when I try to login I get a 403 Forbidden message.

**Navigation to login page is okay**

[image]

**Forbidden error**

[image]

**I know that the cause of this issue is that my login page is not posting the `X-CSRF-Token`.**

Example of the form data posted in my "bad" request:

[image]

The console of my WSO2 instance prints an error like this:

```
WARN {org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger} - potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, ip:IP_ADDRESS, method:POST, uri:/carbon/admin/login_action.jsp, error:required token is missing from the request)
```

Example of the form data posted in a "good" request in a local WSO2 instance:

[image]

**What I have tried:**

I have tried turning compression "off" as suggested by this post: [wso2 api manger carbon page gives 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034714/wso2-api-manger-carbon-page-gives-403-forbidden)

I am not using JDK 1.8.0_151 which is labeled as a version with a bug.

I am able to circumvent the issue if I disable the `csrfguard` in `Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties` but this is a security risk.

I have sticky sessions enabled

Any ideas on why the posting to the login_action.jsp page would return a 403?

**EDIT**

I failed to mention in the post that I am using TLS termination with an AWS load balancer.  I am almost certain that my issue has something to do with that.  This line from my console output details what my error is:

```
Referer domain https:LOAD_BALANCER_URL/carbon/admin/login.jsp does not match request domain: http://LOAD_BALANCER_URL/carbon/admin/js/csrfPrevention.js
```

You can see that the referer is using `https` but the request is using `http`.  I believe that I want the request domain to be `https`, but I'm not sure how to do that.  I think that the first page is making a call to `login.jsp` with `https` and the `login.jsp` page is making a call to the `csrfPrevention.js` page but changing the protocol to http.

Comment: What is your OS and JDK?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the [OS and JDK incompatibilities](https://docs.wso2.com/display/compatibility/Known+Incompatibilities) matrix and make sure you are not using one of these OS JDK pairs.

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and JDK is 1.8.0_181 so there shouldn't be an issue according to the matrix.

Comment: Did you try with JDK is 1.8.0_144? Also, note that when setting compression="off" in catalina-server.xml, there are two places to be updated.

Comment: I have compression turned off for all my connectors in the `catalina-server.xml`.  What is your reasoning behind using JDK 1.8.0_144 if there aren't any known incompatibilities with JDK 1.8.0._181?  I don't want to use an older JDK unless I have to.

Comment: `What is your reasoning behind using JDK 1.8.0_144?`  It is just to check whether this issue is related to JDK or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a load balancer fronting your Identity Server? If so, please verify that you have enabled sticky sessions in your LB. You can find sample NGINX the configurations in the guide - [docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+NGINX](http://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+NGINX)

Comment: I am using an AWS Application Load Balancer and I have sticky sessions enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Lower the version of java JDK to 1.8.0_144.If it's not worked go to this location 
wso2Servers/wso2is-5.5.0/repository/conf/security .
There is a file name Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties.

In that file, there is a line 
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.refererMatchDomain = true

set this to 
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.refererMatchDomain = false

This worked for me.