# Showing "403 forbidden" after login into WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 Carbon Console

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm getting "403 forbidden" error once logged into API Manager 2.0.0 Carbon Console.

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 with Java 1.8.0_144 as recommended by WSO2.

Even I tried to changes values of "org.owasp.csrfguard.Enabled" to "false" in $WSO2APIM_HOME/repository/conf/security/Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties and  "compression" to "off" in $WSO2APIM_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml based on the [blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034714/wso2-api-manger-carbon-page-gives-403-forbidden).

But still not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably only turned compression off one port/connector in catalina-server.xml. There are multiple entries in this config file where you have to turn it off.  Make sure to also turn it of for port 9443.

Comment: Yes, I have updated in all the place. Totally there was 2 entries in catalina-server.xml file.